# HTML5 History API: Refresh and Back issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I'm writing code to create a UX similar to how photos are viewed on Facebook from the timeline...

1. Viewing the timeline, you click on the photo and it opens in a modal
2. You refresh and it goes to a dedicated page for the image
3. You hit back and you return to the timeline

I have most of this working via the **HTML5 History API**. Here is what I'm doing when clicking an image...

1. I use `preventDefault()` to avoid following the link (to the image page) and instead AJAX load a modal with the image
2. I `pushState` the URI of the image page so it appears in the address bar
3. Now I refresh and I'm taken to the dedicated image page (the URI from step #2)
4. Then I hit the "Back" button, and it shows the previous page URI (i.e the timeline) in the address bar but I'm still on the image page.

**Question:** At step #4, is there a way to bypass the history API and just have the browser perform a standard "Back" action so I can return to the previous page (i.e. the timeline)?

Comment: maybe pushState before you load the modal?

Comment: i guess the way you're supposed to do it is listen to onpopstate

Comment: I actually fire `preventDefault()` then `pushState` then the Ajax call. The same problem occurs if I fire `pushState` before the Ajax or in the success callback.

Comment: does it work without refreshing the page (have you implemented onpopstate)?

Comment: If I click the photo from the timeline the modal opens, and then I hit back, it returns to the timeline as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a good ol' fashioned `history.go(-1);` ?

Comment: I was reading `History.getState()` data on refresh to detect if the modal data was present, and if so using `History.go(-1)` but it returned me to the page prior to the the desired page.

Comment: @wdm - you surely mean `history.state`

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

**step 1** -  save the initial page url (which is yet unchanged)

```
var savedPageStateURL = window.location.pathname;
```

**step 2** -  replace current history state (*not* pushing, only replacing)

```
window.history.replaceState( {}, null , url );
```

**step 3** - revert history changes and go back to the first step's state

```
if( 'pushState' in window.history && window.history.state )
    window.history.replaceState( {}, null , savedPageStateURL );
```